# counting http requests

Tags: apache

I want to count the number of all *.png requests on my site. Where/what files do I modify? Both 'success' and 'Not found' results should be counted.

Comment: What web server are you using? If Linux, what distribution? Do you need to do it with php, as tagged, or will any tool suffice?

Comment: I'm not seeing what this has to do with PHP.  It sounds like you just want to parse your server logs and count the number of requests for a given file extension.  Grep (or any grep-like tool) can accomplish this easily enough.

Comment: Read the question, read the tag, do you think we can read minds?

Comment: Yes, Apache server. Thanks for the suggesstions of parsing server logs. I thought I had to modify a server configuration file. I added php tag only because I use PHP. This is my first-time posting here.

Answer (score 0):

you can get this info from apache logs, if you are using apache.  You can use a tool like webalizer or just write a script/program in your favorite language with regexes to accomplish this...